# Bottom Bracket on a Trek CrossRip Comp 2016?

Tags: bottom-bracket, trek

I'm trying to change my crank set from a FSA Vero 602 50/39/30 set to a FSA Gossamer Pro 386ABS 48/32.  I have the new crank set but I need to know what my bracket shell standard is.  I was wondering if anyone out there has a Trek CrossRip Comp 2016?  Would you happen to know if the bracket Trek used on these bike was the same and if so, do you know the bracket standard without me taking it apart.  I am currently using the bike on a trainer and really don't want to tear it down to find out.  I would like to get the bracket before I do this.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  It's a big help.  Now, I have somewhere to start.

Comment: Welcome to the site! The "Stack Exchange way" of saying thanks for an answer that helped you is to upvote it, by clicking the arrow button next to it. As the person who asked the question, you can also "accept" one answer that you feel best solves your problem. Since there isn't really a full answer yet, maybe that's not yet appropriate. There's more information at our short site [tour]. One thing we would encourage you to do is to come back and post a full answer yourself if you find out.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Trek tech site the 2016 Crossrip Comp was outfitted with a VP Components 68mm x 110.5mm Square Taper Bottom Bracket.

The BB standard for this bike is BSA-Threaded (See [linked chart](https://wheelsmfg.com/bb-standards) for more details)

Suitable replacements are

- [BB Shimano BB-UN26 68 x 110mm](http://www.jensonusa.com/Shimano-UN-26-Bottom-Bracket-English-68mm-X-110mm)
- [BB Shimano BB-UN55 68 x 110mm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005DTIG9U)

With the only difference being the quality.

Any BSA Threaded bottom bracket that is for a 30mm spindle would work. BB 386 is just a longer standard than the BB30 standard with the same 30mm diameter.

[This one should work](https://wheelsmfg.com/bottom-brackets/threaded-to-30mm-angular-contact-bb-black.html) for your crossrip.

**NOTE** You WILL need 30mm spindle spacers which would sit outside of the bottom bracket, as the 386 EVO spindle is much longer.

Also expect the life on these bearings to be much shorter as they will be further away from the bike, due to external cups, with smaller bearings then usual (BSA Threaded(smaller shell) -> BB30(bigger spindle) doesn't leave a lot of room for bearings!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonable sure the Vero Cranks were square taper, which means you have a threaded bottom bracket shell.

I don't know for sure that a threaded bracket to 386 EVO adapter exists.